# Is it possible to stack a row below respective column in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Hello i am stuck in this problem. I have 2 Rows and 4 Columns ( col-md-8 & col md-4 in each row).
Structure is like below (also attached screenshot and code):

Inside container

```
 Row 1 Column 1 (md-8)      Row 1 Column 2 (md-4) [Accordion]
 Row 2 Column 1 (md-8)      Row 2 Column 2 (md-4)
```

The Column 2 of Row 1 is accordion and when it is expanded it takes whole row 2 with it but i want it to take just column below it which is Row 2 Column 2

See the attached images to have a better understanding:
R2C1 has already space greater than R2C2
[image]
When accordion is expanded R2C1 gets too much extra space as compared to R2C2
[image]

Is there any thing i am missing or fix this? Thank you.

Here is the code demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-5-q5cctv?file=src%2Findex.html

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="fw-1">Row 1 Column 1</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="my-4">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus eos, enim quibusdam nemo tempore modi ducimus eveniet similique, voluptatibus quas totam suscipit eius error accusantium veritatis velit, quis reprehenderit unde.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">

                            <span>R1 C2</span>


                            <!-- <i class="bi bi-printer-fill"> bi bi-envelope-at-fill </i> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                                <div class="accordion-item">
                                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne"
                                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                                            Accordion Item #1
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                                        aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">Photo Editing,.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="accordion-item">
                                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo"
                                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                                            Accordion Item #2
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                                        aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is
                                            intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the
                                            second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some
                                            actual content.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="accordion-item">
                                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree"
                                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                                            Accordion Item #3
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                                        aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is
                                            intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the
                                            third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms
                                            of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first
                                            glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world
                                            application.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="fw-1">Row 2 Column 1</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="my-4">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus eos, enim quibusdam nemo tempore modi ducimus eveniet similique, voluptatibus quas totam suscipit eius error accusantium veritatis velit, quis reprehenderit unde.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                        

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">

                            <span>R2 C2</span>


                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="my-4">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus eos, enim quibusdam nemo tempore modi ducimus eveniet similique, voluptatibus quas totam suscipit eius error accusantium veritatis velit, quis reprehenderit unde.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <footer class="pt-3 mt-4 text-muted border-top">
            © 2023
        </footer>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the content in second row pushed down after the accordion show, you shouldn't put them on different rows.
Inside container you can use structure like this:

```
<div class"row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div>Some content here</div>
    <div>Some content here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div>Some content here</div>
    <div>Some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that I removed structures like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    Some content here
  </div>
</div>
```

because they are not needed here and you should use flexbox wisely.

Code snippet below, you can run it full page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
          <span class="fw-1">Row 1 Column 1</span>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus eos, enim quibusdam nemo tempore modi ducimus eveniet similique, voluptatibus quas totam suscipit eius error accusantium veritatis velit, quis reprehenderit unde.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
          <span class="fw-1">Row 2 Column 1</span>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus eos, enim quibusdam nemo tempore modi ducimus eveniet similique, voluptatibus quas totam suscipit eius error accusantium veritatis velit, quis reprehenderit unde.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
          R1 C2
          <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                  Accordion Item #1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                   aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">Photo Editing,.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                  Accordion Item #2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                   aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  Placeholder content for this accordion, which is
                  intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the
                  second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some
                  actual content.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                  Accordion Item #3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                   aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  Placeholder content for this accordion, which is
                  intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the
                  third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms
                  of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first
                  glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world
                  application.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-white rounded-3">
          R2 C2
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus eos, enim quibusdam nemo tempore modi ducimus eveniet similique, voluptatibus quas totam suscipit eius error accusantium veritatis velit, quis reprehenderit unde.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="pt-3 mt-4 text-muted border-top">
      © 2023
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```